# How do you print different templates in netsuite?

Tags: printing, netsuite

I am trying to find the correct template and id to use for a hotprint of an advanced pdf template of an Item Fulfillment.

The hot print url is (with the id bolded) https://system.na3.netsuite.com/app/accounting/print/hotprint.nl?regular=T&sethotprinter=T&id=**7600**&label=Packing%20Slip&printtype=packingslip&trantype=itemship&orgtrantype=TrnfrOrd&auxtrans=7605

For some reason only certain id=# seems to affect the outcome and the ids I have got to work for two different templates don't match the Custom Transaction Forms ID or the Advanced pdf script id. (example most ids=template 1, while 168,4954, and seemingly random other ids=template 2) I am very confused on how netsuite resolves the hot print url as it normally doesn't include the template= part though I have seen others use it for invoice print urls.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The parameters at the end of the url (the stuff after the `?`) are used by Netsuite to control settings used by the webpage which prints the PDFs for you.

In this case, `&id=#####` refers to the internal id of the document you are printing.  You can see this by going to the document, right clicking, selecting inspect, and typing `nlapiGetRecordId()` into the console.  When you click Print, you should see that same number after `&id=#####`.

`&template=###` refers to the template you are printing.  If you go to Customization -> Forms -> Advanced PDF/HTML Templates, you'll notice a Script ID field in the table.  If you substitute the correct Script ID in for the number in `&template=###`, you'll notice you generate the same PDF.  This Script ID acts the same as the number that was previously there.

The reason you're seeing unusual results when you change those numbers is because you're mismatching a record with a template not built for it.  So it won't print exactly right, but will sometimes execute anyways.

Anyways, this sort of parameter scheme is a similar scheme to how Suitelets and Restlets work, so in the future, you might experience this sort of thing again.

EDIT:  For those reading this in the future, please read the comments.

Comment: I tried using the template script in the url below but it is still using the default print method. could there be another way to define the print template? "https:// system. na3. netsuite. com/app/accounting/print/hotprint.nl?regular=T&sethotprinter=T&id=24218&printtype=packingslip&trantype=itemship&orgtrantype=TrnfrOrd&auxtrans=24219&template=custtmpl%20_125_4527362_813"

Comment: Hmmm... what type of document are you trying to print?  And you're trying to print the packing slip for that document, right?  Is the template for packing slips built for that specific type of document?

Comment: Actually hold on... let me check if it will only print the default and no others... I explored the Suitescript 2.0 API and it looked that way so I imagine their internal process works that way too.

Comment: Hey there, I just tried it, and yeah, it's looking like it's only printing the current default PDF template for that form.  So that means changing the &template probably woldn't do anything.  You'll have to use Suitescript in order to print an alternative template probably (not too hard actually... just a few steps).  Either that or some somewhat messy Freemarker Templating in the Template.

Comment: Bad news but thank you for the advice. I will keep digging into it and let you know what I find. I think next I will try and see if it is possible with the render Module. Thanks for the help

Answer (score -1):

To customize a packing slip and return form:
If you are printing packing slips and need some customization, you can use a custom invoice form when printing packing slips. For example, you can customize an invoice form to hide the fulfilled item tax rate and amount, and the order total. Then, when you print the packing slip using the custom form through mass print, choose the the packing slip shows the customized information.